# Vertical align inline text/image

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/743kzyag/)

I have a title and subtitle in my header:

```
<header>
    <h1>Article Title</h1>
    <p>By John Smith<span class="right">100 likes<img src="http://placehold.it/44x44"/></span></p>
</header>
```

The subtitle needs to have a name on the left and the number of likes on the right - with an image.

I want the text in the vertical center of the image so I've used:

```
img{
      vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This works for the like count, but not for the name. How can the name appear in the same vertical alignment?

Comment: [Like this](https://jsfiddle.net/743kzyag/2/)?

Comment: Think s/he might want to maintain the space, make flex-box would be a good solution for this?

Comment: Can't use flexbox im afraid

Comment: @notulysses thanks but likes need to be right aligned

Answer (score 1):

The modern way of doing it with flexbox.

```css
header p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

header p span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Article Title</h1>
  <p>
    <span>By John Smith</span>
    <span>204 likes<img src="http://placehold.it/44x44"/></span>
  </p>
</header>
```

#### Original answer

If it's OK to add a `<span>` around the name, read on.

```css
span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.right {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>Article Title</h1>
    <p><span>By John Smith</span><span class="right">204 likes<img src="http://placehold.it/44x44"/></span></p>
</header>
```

**Fiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/L4n50f49/

Comment: doesn't actually work. change the font size to be large than the image

Answer (score -1):

You can do a list and make it display in inline block :

```
<ul>
   <li>Name</li>
   <li>Like Counts</li>
   <li><img ... /></li>
</ul>

li
{
display:inline-block
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

create this style
`<style>
div.LeftColumn    { width: 170px; float: left;   background-image:url("http://placehold.it/44x44"); }
</style>`

change to DIV and assign style.

```
<p><div class="LeftColumn">By John Smith  100 likes</div></p>
```

If you want more of a box look you will need to tweak further, but this gives you the text within the image.

Answer (score -1):

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
        John Smith
        </td>
        <td>
          100 Likes
        </td>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/44x44"/></td>
      </tr>
      
    </table>
```